# Проблема с импортом CSV файлов

Tags: mysql

Как видно на 1-й картинке, я импортировал данные из Excel, где дата в виде 1/1/16 2:00, но когда я импортировал в Sequel Pro, то она стала в виде 0001-01-16 02:00:00. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам в любом случае придется как-то преобразовать файл SQL-дампа, чтобы в нем оказались корректные дата и время. Например, средствами MySQL решить эту задачу можно при помощи функции `STR_TO_DATE()`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("1/1/16 2:00", "%e/%c/%y %l:%i");
+----------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE("1/1/16 2:00", "%e/%c/%y %l:%i") |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 2016-01-01 02:00:00                          |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Таким образом, в дампе следует заменить строки вида `"1/1/16 2:00"` на `STR_TO_DATE("1/1/16 2:00", "%e/%c/%y %l:%i")`. Проще всего это сделать при помощи регулярных выражений, многие редакторы их поддерживают, например, тот же Sublime Text. Регулярное выражение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
("\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}")
```

строка замены

```
STR_TO_DATE(\1, "%e/%c/%y %l:%i")
```